# If user changes value of select with ctrl+shift+i

Tags: php

How can i protect my website from this 
I have this php code

```
$gender=$_POST['pol'];
```

And this HTML code

```
    <input type="radio"  name="pol"  class="pad"   value="male" >
<b id="A">Male</label></b>
<label><input  type="radio"  name="pol"  class="pad"value="female">
<b id="A">Female</label></b>
```

But if user changes value of input it will insert in database something different.So how can i protect my website from this.

Comment: you should have validation in the server side

Comment: Use something like ENUM to enter constant values into database

Comment: If you think your only problem is that someone may insert something wrong in your database, you never heard about the horrors of SQL Injection. Google it and despair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!in_array($_POST['pol'],["male","female"])){
    //handle error
}
```